# How do I take a JSON string and select a random entry and get the variables from that entry

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have the following json..

```
{
    "Followers": [{
        "ID": 0,
        "Username": "nutty",
        "Game": "Just Chatting",
        "Viewers": 200,
        "Image": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_nutty-1920x1080.jpg"
    }, {
        "ID": 1,
        "Username": "CloneKorp",
        "Game": "Software and Game Development",
        "Viewers": 31,
        "Image": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_clonekorp-1920x1080.jpg"
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "Username": "kingswarrior9953",
        "Game": "Art",
        "Viewers": 1,
        "Image": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_kingswarrior9953-1920x1080.jpg"
    }]
}
```

I'd like to do something like..

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
int SelectedViewers = data["Followers"][1]["Viewers"];
```

Where it would grab the second entry (the ID of 1 entry) and set the variable of "Viewers" to 31. The number would be a random number based on the count of all the entries, but I'm not to that point yet.

However, this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what is broken here?

Comment: What do you mean by *However, this doesn't seem to work*. What errors do you get, what do you expect to happen and what does happpen?

Comment: I was getting an error about casting. But I got it worked out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing casting here:

```
int SelectedViewers = Int32.Parse((string)data["Followers"][1]["Viewers"]);
```

The above should work.

Comment: int selectedViewers = Int32.Parse((string)data["Followers"][id]["Viewers"]); So when I change this to an ID, it is giving me the error of "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." I get that it is reading "id" instead of recognizing that the line before it is "int id=3;" Any ideas on how to make it so I can set the ID elsewhere and then have it read the proper record?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   using Newtonsoft.Json;
   using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    var followers = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["Followers"];
    var id=1;
    
    int selectedViewers = followers.Where(f=> (int)f["ID"]==id)
                                   .Select(f => (int) f["Viewers"])
                                   .FirstOrDefault();  //31
```

Comment: (24,37): error CS1061: 'JArray' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'JArray' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @LanceLake I updated my answer. Added 2 using  links.